# Installing git plugin in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, git, egit

I am trying to install eclipse plugin EGit from the update site: http://download.eclipse.org/egit/updates

But I am getting the following error, please help me with this. I am using Eclipse Juno on Mac Osx

**Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
Software currently installed: SVNKit Client Adapter (Not required) 1.7.9.2 (org.tigris.subversion.clientadapter.svnkit.feature.feature.group 1.7.9.2)
Missing requirement: SVNKit pure Java Subversion Library 1.7.11.r9959_v20130906_1728 (org.tmatesoft.svnkit 1.7.11.r9959_v20130906_1728) requires 'bundle com.trilead.ssh2 [1.0.0,2.0.0)' but it could not be found
Cannot satisfy dependency:
From: SVNKit Client Adapter (Not required) 1.7.9.2 (org.tigris.subversion.clientadapter.svnkit.feature.feature.group 1.7.9.2)
To: org.tmatesoft.svnkit [1.7.0,1.8.0)**

Answer (score 0):

You can integrate Git-GUI with Eclipse as an alternative to EGit.

See this two part YouTube tutorial specific to Windows:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DcM1xOiaidk

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1OrPJClD92s

Comment: I am getting exactly the same error when I ma trying to install the maven plugin : m2e
update site: http://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/releases

Comment: which eclipse version

Comment: Can you upgrade to kepler?

Comment: also did u try to install from market place?Help-->Marketplace

Comment: Thanks I am able to install with Eclipse Kepler.