# SVNKit error when installing ADT 23.0.3 in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, adt, svnkit

Today my Eclipse 4.4 tells me I can update to ADT 23.0.3.1327240. Yay! (I don't see anything related to SVNKit.) So I hit "Finish". I get:

```
'Updating Software' has encountered a problem.
Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.

Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
Software currently installed: SVNKit Client Adapter (Not required) 1.8.9 (org.tigris.subversion.clientadapter.svnkit.feature.feature.group 1.8.9)
Missing requirement: SVNKit pure Java Subversion Library 1.8.6.r10298_v20140730_2254 (org.tmatesoft.svnkit 1.8.6.r10298_v20140730_2254) requires 'bundle com.trilead.ssh2 [1.0.0,2.0.0)' but it could not be found
Cannot satisfy dependency:
From: SVNKit Client Adapter (Not required) 1.8.9 (org.tigris.subversion.clientadapter.svnkit.feature.feature.group 1.8.9)
To: org.tmatesoft.svnkit [1.8.0,1.9.0)
```

(sigh) Sometimes I hate Eclipse. And ADT. Especially ADT.

What can I do?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/19509890/421049.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/19772493/421049.

Comment: See also https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/cleartk-users/zClGYneeg7k.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made this go away:

1. I went into my Eclipse installation details and uninstalled SVNKit.
2. I updated Eclipse (4.4.1RC1) and all available plugins (e.g. ADT 23.0.3). This time it was successful.
3. I installed new software directly from the Subclipse site. It showed that both SVNKit and SVNKit Client Adapter were available, so I installed them. This worked fine, except that Eclipse crashed when restarting. Manually restarting after that worked.
4. I updated software and a new version of SVNKit 1.8.6 suddenly was available. I installed it.

Now my Eclipse installation seems to be working and up-to-date. I suppose it was something corrupted with the SVNKit installation, which comes with Subclipse.

My Subclipse installation is set to use JavaHL instead of SVNKit. I'm going to leave it alone for the meantime.

Answer (score 3):

This software is Not required. So exclude it from installation(remove selection in left box). I have done so and succeeded with Subclipse.